# JWT - validate scopes and/or claims against issuer

Tags: jwt

Is it logical or recommended to validate the presence of a specific scope and/or claim against the issuer of the JWT?

For example, we will have a couple of different **issuers** of JWTs:

- One for employees, controlled by Active Directory
- Another for customer access, more of a custom auth mechanism

There'll be some sort of admin-related scope or claim, but that should only ever be set by the employee JWT issuer, never by the customer JWT issuer.

In theory since we control both JWT mechanisms, this is firstly controlled by the implementation. However, it seems like a best practice should be to not only validate the issuer as being valid, but that the claims they issued are appropriate.

To me the answer is simple: "yes that validation should happen", but I haven't seen many recommendations in that regard. Most people talk about validating the issuer in isolation from other parts of the token.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isn't JWS what you want?

Comment: @SirMuffington I think that is one part of the equation (it was kind of implied, but I should have mentioned that). From my perspective, a valid signature must be paired with validating the issuer (and/or other things), otherwise all you're doing is verifying that the token hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really like the `admin` scope idea, so thought about it more. It makes more sense for the employee JWT issuer to use the same or additional scopes as the customer JWT issuer, probably many of them.

For example, a JWT issued to me as an employee may include:

- Scopes that a customer would have:

  - customer.read
  - customer.write
- Scopes specific to an "admin":

  - configuration.read
  - configuration.write

Secondly, the latest [JSON Web Token Best Current Practices](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8725) has this to say in section 3.12:

> Given the broad diversity of JWT usage and applications, the best combination of types, required claims, values, Header Parameters, key usages, and issuers to differentiate among different kinds of JWTs will, in general, be application-specific.

So being application-specific, I'd say if you expect two issuers of JWTs, it does make sense to verify a sensitive scope or claim came from the issuer you expected it to come from.